# Configuring routers on Cisco

Tags: cisco, router, interface

If I have three routers R1, R2, and R3 that are interlinked, then when configuring, do I have to give the command:

```
description Link to R2
description Link to R3
```

when configuring R1?

Comment: Those are just descriptions to help you identify what the port is used for. It doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A router will function the same with or without interface descriptions. It is a very good practice to add interface descriptions because that can help you later on when you have forgotten how you connected things. It is a good habit to develop.

Also, when you ask for help from someone not familiar with your network (such as here), having descriptions on the interfaces will go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Description is just a commenta given by respective engineer for future acknowledgments   and for  easy understanding to know on this interface which device is connected . Description can be anything it might be comment or ticket number it's upto team  to  remember for future acknowledgments

Router(config)# int ethernet F0/1
Router(config)# description " cosole access"

Like this network engineers have feasible to add description to interface for future acknowledgments.